# Simple code failing with error The relationship between the two objects cannot be defined

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

The below code is failing with the error message shown. Can you help me understand why? I am pulling the entity and making the change within the same using statement so I cannot understand why is more than one context at work?

```
using (var db = new Context())
{
    Company c = db.Companies.Where(x => x.CompanyId == 1).FirstOrDefault();
    c.Name = "TEST HERE"; 
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

> The relationship between the two objects cannot be defined because they are attached to different ObjectContext objects.

**EDIT**

The below code is the Company class, which is using a different context to get the products (I have just realised, this isn't my code). How can I fix this so that I can update the entity without EF trying to update the Products collection which isnt required or allowed because it is read only?

```
public class Company
{
    [Required]
    public Int32 CompanyId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products
    {
        get
        {
            using (var db = new Context())
            {
                return db.Products.Where(c => c.CID == CompanyId).ToList();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this using inside another using or is there any db operations before this one that is not saved to db?

Comment: The using is just inside the controller, nothing else. Please see my edit.

Comment: Can you edit the second part of code? If so adding db.Dispose(); under get method inside the using can work.

Comment: Do you mean to add that call outside the getter? Won't this already dispose because it is in a using statement?

Comment: get
        {
            using (var db = new Context())
            {
                return db.Products.Where(c => c.CID == CompanyId).ToList();
    db.Dipose();        }
        }

Comment: you shouldnt mix data getters and model , when you retrive a company with a virtual products the products will be loaded "automaticaly" using include in query, without your database context code. (that is if it is set up in same context...)

Comment: "you shouldnt mix data getters and model" What does this mean exactly? Should I remove this Getter?